# Using strtol to validate integer input in ANSI C

Tags: c, string, ansi-c, strtol

I am new to programming and to C in general and am currently studying it at university. This is for an assignment so I would like to avoid direct answers but are more after tips or hints/pushes in the right direction.

I am trying to use strtol to validate my keyboard input, more specifically, test whether the input is numeric. I have looked over other questions on here and other sites and I have followed instructions given to other users but it hasn't helped me.

From what I have read/ understand of *strtol* (long int strtol (const char* str, char** endptr, int base);)  if the *endptr* is not a null pointer the function will set the value of the *endptr* to the first character after the number.

So if I was to enter 84948ldfk, the *endptr* would point to 'l', telling me there is characters other than numbers in the input and which would make it invalid.

However in my case, what is happening, is that no matter what I enter, my program is returning an Invalid input. Here is my code:

```
void run_perf_square(int *option_stats)
{
   char input[MAX_NUM_INPUT + EXTRA_SPACES]; /*MAX_NUM_INPUT + EXTRA_SPACES are defined
                                              *in header file. MAX_NUM_INPUT = 7 
                                              *and EXTRA_SPACES 
                                              *(for '\n' and '\0') = 2. */
   char *ptr;
   unsigned num=0; /*num is unsigned as it was specified in the start up code for the 
                    *assignment. I am not allow to change it*/

   printf("Perfect Square\n");
   printf("--------------\n");
   printf("Enter a positive integer (1 - 1000000):\n");
   if(fgets(input, sizeof input, stdin) != NULL)
   {
      num=strtol(input, &ptr, 10);
      if( num > 1000001)
      {
         printf("Invalid Input! PLease enter a positive integer between 1 
                  and 1000000\n");
         read_rest_of_line();        /*clears buffer to avoid overflows*/
         run_perf_square(option_stats);
      }
      else if (num <= 0)
      {
         printf("Invalid Input! PLease enter a positive integer between 1 
                  and 1000000\n");
         run_perf_square(option_stats);
      }
      else if(ptr != NULL)
      {
         printf("Invalid Input! PLease enter a positive integer between 1 
                  and 1000000\n");
         run_perf_square(option_stats);
      }
      else
      {
         perfect_squares(option_stats, num);
      }
   }
}
```

Can anyone help me in the right direction? Obviously the error is with my *if(ptr != NULL)* condition, but as I understand it seems right. As I said, I have looked at previous questions similar to this and took the advice in the answers but it doesn't seem to work for me. Hence, I thought it best to ask for my help tailored to my own situation.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi chux, my input has to be greater than 0, can't equal it.

Comment: `else if (num <= 0)` _is_ your error condition.

Comment: Ah yes, thanks chux I see what your saying. Corrected now!

Comment: Do not post your own later answer as part of the question.  Post the answer below.  See [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).  Post rolled back.

Answer (score 6):

You're checking the outcome of `strtol` in the wrong order, check `ptr` first, also don't check ptr against `NULL`, derference it and check that it points to the `NUL` (`'\0'`) string terminator.

```
if (*ptr == '\0') {
  // this means all characters were parsed and converted to `long`
}
else {
  // this means either no characters were parsed correctly in which
  // case the return value is completely invalid
  // or
  // there was a partial parsing of a number to `long` which is returned
  // and ptr points to the remaining string
}
```

`num > 1000001` also needs to be `num > 1000000`

`num < 0` also needs to be `num < 1`

You can also with some reorganising and logic tweaks collapse your sequence of if statements down to only
a single invalid branch and a okay branch.

Comment: Thanks for your help Troy!

I made the changes you suggested, but the code is excuting the same. My input validation branches are now:
 if(*ptr == '\0' && num < 1000001 && num > 0)
 {
    perfect_squares(option_stats, num);
 }
 else
 {
   printf("Error Message);
   if(num > 1000000)
   { 
      read_rest_of_line();
   }
   run_perf_square(option_stats);
 }

Comment: Better solution might be to ditch `strtol`, `fgets` completely and use `fscanf`.

Comment: Yeah, I have exactly what you have suggested in your link and its not working. I'm not sure if I can use `fscanf`, our instructor is keen on us using `fgets`

Comment: `if (*ptr == '\0')` causes common valid input like `"123\n"` to fail as the conversion was stopped by `'\n'`.   `if (*ptr == '\0')`  also  incorrectly passes  the unusual case of  `*ptr == '\0'` as valid input.

Answer (score 3):

OP would like to avoid direct answers ....

**validate integer input**

1. Separate I/O from validation - 2 different functions.
2. I/O: Assume hostile input.  (Text, too much text, too little text.  I/O errors.)  Do you want to consume leading spaces as part of I/O? Do you want to consume leading `0` as part of I/O? (suggest not)
3. Validate the string (NULL, lead space OK?, digits after a trailing space, too short, too long, under-range, over-range,  Is 123.0 an OK integer)
4. `strtol()` is your friend to do the heavy conversion lifting.  Check how `errno` should be set and tested afterward.  Use the `endptr`.  Should its value be set before.  How to test afterward.  It consume leading spaces, is that OK?  It converts text to a `long`, but OP  wants the nebulous "integer".

Qapla'

Answer (score 0):

The function strtol returns long int, which is a signed value.  I suggest that you use another variable (entry_num), which you could test for <0, thus detecting negative numbers.

I would also suggest that regex could test string input for digits and valid input, or you could use strtok and anything but digits as the delimiter ;-)  Or you could scan the input string using validation, something like:

```
int validate_input ( char* input )
{
    char *p = input;
    if( !input ) return 0;
    for( p=input; *p && (isdigit(*p) || iswhite(*p)); ++p )
    {
    }
    if( *p ) return 0;
    return 1;
}
```